# Difference between sphinxcontrib.napoleon and numpy.numpydoc

Tags: python, numpy, python-sphinx, numpydoc, sphinx-napoleon

I am writing documentation for a Python project using [Numpy-style docstrings](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt).

[numpydoc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc) and [napoleon](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/napoleon.html) are two Sphinx extensions that parse Numpy-style docstrings to generate documentation. The first one is used for the Numpy project itself, the second is shipped with Sphinx.

What are the pros and cons of using one extension over the other?

Answer (score 15):

The resulting format of each a bit different, and the default behavior of `napoleon` links to known datatypes in the `python` documentation, and it is slightly more condensed (`numpydoc` displays a bit like how it appears in the docstring). Below are examples of each, both using the default sphinx theme.

[An issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/3974) in `astropy`'s issue tracker that states `napolean` is a hard dependency for `IPython`, and they have since migrated from `numpydoc` to `napolean`.

They mention it has stricter syntax requirements, but I haven't tested either too much to comment on that.

---

**napoleon**

---

[image]

---

**numpydoc**

---

[image]

Comment: What sphinx-theme was used for this?

Comment: @bad_coder I think it was Alabaster.